# ffmpeg unsupported video codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to convert a .flv into an mpeg with this code:

```
ffmpeg -i my.flv -target ntsc-dvd -aspect 4:3 my.mpg
```

And I get a lot of these here:

```
[flv @ 0x5597b8]Unsupported video codec (7)
```

and then:

```
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
    Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Unsupported codec (id=0) for input stream #0.0
```

But when I ask ffmpeg for formats flv is supported.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash video is the file (container) format not the video codec.  In your example, the container contains two streams and it is stating that it doesn't support the video codec that stream 0.0 uses.  Do you know what video codec it is?

See the [wikipedia article on Flash video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) and the [wikipedia article on container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29#Multimedia_container_formats) for more details.

Comment: Stream #0.0, 30.00 fps(r): Video: 0x0007
Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x000a, 44100 Hz, stereo

Comment: Video: 716 Kbps, 854*480 (16:9), at 25.000 fps, AVC (Main@L3.0)(CABAC/3 Ref Frames); Audio: 128 Kbps, 44.1 KHz, " channels, AAC (LC)

Answer (score 0):

rename your my.flv to be my.mp4 and try that.